# C# WPF matrix visualisation component

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to visualise large 2-dimensional matrixes in wpf application (like 10000x10000). Please advise ready WPF component to do that.

Comment: Do you have to represent each of the 100 million cells?  Or can you reduce/compact the cells?

Comment: Some of WPF controls support virtualization, which means that you can display any number of items without significant performance drop. Take a look at [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx)

Comment: @GarryVass, i have color for each cell element and i want to visualize that.

Comment: @Ondra, thanks. Will  try to use that component.

Comment: @Frank59 4 bytes per pixel * 10k * 10k gives 400 megabytes, which is borderline ok, but the binding will be unbearable.  Even with virtualization.  Thinking across the boxes for a moment...  Would you accept an answer based upon a 'DeepZoom' paradigm?  Something rather like Google Earth zoom in and pan?  It's a total departure from your original design...  I can provide an answer along those lines if it's of any use

Comment: @GarryVass comment leads to a question: What do you mean by a matrix? a) an image - matrix of pixels, or b) mathematical matrix - grid of values?

Comment: @Ondra, is that for me or Frank? If for me, I imagined a large matrix along the lines of a heat map. Each value in the matrix being coded into a colour (hence 4 bytes needed to represent each cell). Asking the user to look at 10k x 10k numbers would be wildly out of whack with human factors. So I was thinking along the lines of the 'deep zoom' pattern, rather like Google Earth.

Comment: @GarryVass The question was for Frank. I understood from your answer that you expect it to be an image, but my answer (the DataGrid) is a solution for texts

Comment: @Ondra, your idea is fine also. And it's indeed the initial starting point if nothing else.

Comment: @Ondra, i working with large  mathematical matrix and i want to see value distribution inside my matrix.